# How does Electronics work for repairing the Mako if more than one person has it?

Tags: mass-effect

I currently have 2 members in my party with the **Electronics** skill (Garrus and Liara), which, in addition to its other functions, also serves as the baseline for hull repair of the Mako. Every point in Electronics increases the amount of hull repaired by 200.

If I have both of them in my party, whose skill is used? Will the game automatically choose the highest Electronics skill in my party? Will (and I *highly* doubt this, but I'm wondering for completion's sake) the amount repaired *stack*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, [the skills stack](http://www.gamespot.com/mass-effect/forum/confused-about-first-aid-skill-41801385/). This post is about medical gel, but if you scroll down you'll see someone who looks like they've actually done the leg works to do the research and states that

> Electronics repair bonuses stack as well.

Comment: Well, that's a pleasant surprise!